# Conditional rendering in asp.net core razor, without evaluating expression

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an asp.net core MVC application, and I'm using an if statement for conditional rendering.

In the following code snippet:

```
if (@item.Date.HasValue)
{
    <div>
        <text>@Common.DateConverter.GetHijriDateString(item.Date.Value)</text>
    </div>
}
```

Why is it throwing a (InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value.) exception, if the value is null, even though I have placed a check for null value in the enclosing if statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Razor expression is wrong. Your `if` didn't start with an `@` so it's just a HTML not the razor. So even though `@item.Date.HasValue` would run fine, it will fail on the `GetHijriDateString` parameter `item.Date.Value` when the date doesn't have a value.

To fix it:

```
@if (item.Date.Hasvalue)
{
    ...
}
```